# Git: failed to push some refs although I have done git pull

Tags: git

I started to get 'failed to push some refs' error when I changed some files and tried to do push. Most instructions tell to do git pull first. I have done it and git says everything is up to date. Any idea how to solve the error? I also started getting 'no version information available' message, I don't know does that have anything to do with the error.

```
git push origin master
git: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by git)
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 
To git@[mydomain].beanstalkapp.com:/repo-git.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@[mydomain].beanstalkapp.com:/repo-git.git'
```

Comment: What happens if you clone the repository in another location and try to push on it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The error is that somebody else has pushed in the `master` branch and you would overwrite their change if `git` allowed you to push (this is what `non-fast forward` error means). So you need to merge your local `master` branch with the remote `master` branch.

This can happen if you did the `git pull` while the local branch was not the `master` branch. If you only want to push the branch you are working on and not the `master` branch, you need to tell it to `git` using the complete form of `git-push`:

```
$ git push remote local-branch:remote-branch
```

Comment: How would I merge local master branch with the remote master branch? Anyway I noticed with git branch that I was using a branch called (No branch).
I did checkout master and now I can do push / pull

Comment: When you do `git pull`, it does a ` git fetch` followed by a `git merge` with the remote branch the current branch is tracking. You can do a manual merge with `git merge master`.

Answer (score 6):

The best possible answer is on Git help [here](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors)

**Dealing with non-fast-forward errors**

From time to time, you may encounter this error while pushing commits (`git push origin master`) to GitHub:

```
To https://github.com/user/repo.git  
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)  
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'  
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected  
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  
See the  'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

This error can be a bit overwhelming at first; do not fear!

Simply put, Git can't make the change on the remote without losing commits, so it refuses the push. Usually, this is caused by another user pushing to the same branch.

You can remedy this by fetching and merging the remote branch:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin master
```

Or, you can simply use git pull to perform both commands at once:

```
git pull origin master
```

In some cases, this error is a result of destructive changes made locally by using commands like `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`. While you can override the remote by adding --force to the push command, you should only do so if you are absolutely certain this is what you want to do. Force-pushes can cause issues for other users that have fetched the remote branch, and is considered bad practice. When in doubt, don't force-push.

Comment: merge: origin - not something we can merge

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your branch is unprotected, or developer can push is checked.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to verify that the pull actually worked.  It is possible the merge (which is part of a pull) failed.

When I had this error message I failed to notice the pull failed.  The pull failed due to some uncommitted file changes (unrelated to the files I was trying to push) which caused the merge to fail. I reverted those file changes (because they were not important) and then did a pull again.  After the successful pull, the push worked.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the error happens when you put the wrong branch name into your push command.

For example, say you're on a branch called `iss8`, but you tell git to push to `iss3` (like I just did), you'll get the same error.

```
$ git push origin iss3
error: src refspec iss3 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@myhost.com:myuser/myproject.git'
```

Hmm, check status:

```
$ git status 
On branch iss8
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Oh, look, I'm on a different branch.  Thanks git for not letting me do something really dumb.

```
$ git push origin iss8
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 2.62 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@myhost.com:myuser/myproject.git
 * [new branch]      iss8 -> iss8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) git stash 
2) git pull
3) git push
```

My Original Error:

[image]

After "git stash"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this command  `git push -f origin master`